# form_load subroutine in MS Access VBA

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, form-load

I am writing a code in MS Access VBA, which is as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "loggedIn = " + CStr(loggedIn)
    If (loggedIn = 1) Then
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to decide whether to load the form or not based on `loggedIn` variable. If `loggedIn` variable is 1, form shall be loaded. If the same is not 1, form shall not be loaded.

Issue that I am facing is that, whatever I do in ELSE part of the code above, I am not able to stop the form from loading.

How can I achieve this?

Pls comment if any additional information is required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `loggedIn` value is available at form open, you could cancel the form open event.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Cancel = Not (loggedIn = 1)
End Sub
```

If the value of `loggedIn` is not available until the form's load event, you can close the form.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If loggedIn <> 1 Then
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If
End Sub
```